# how to solve uiscrollview error

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uiscrollview

Can any one tell me why I am getting this error ?

> [myClassName
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8ad5a90'

I know what does it means but in myClassName class I didn't use any uitableview!!!! I have a scrollview in this class not tableView so I could not find why I am getting this error.

EDITED :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
imageIndex = 0;
int count =0;
int totalScrollRow = 0;

myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 397);
NSLog(@"%f",myScroll.contentSize.height);

volPhotoApp = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

volPhotoApp.photoGalleryIndex = 0 ;

eventRow = [volPhotoApp.volPhotoArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
numberOfImages = [eventRow.photoArray count];

if (numberOfImages == 0)
{
    UILabel *zeroLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
    zeroLabel.text = @"No Images..";

    [myScroll addSubview:zeroLabel];
    return;
}

header.enabled =NO;
[header setTitle:eventRow.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

CGRect contentRect = myScroll.bounds;

CGFloat boundX = contentRect.origin.x;

CGFloat boundY = contentRect.origin.y;

CGRect frame1 ;

for (int i=0, X=5 ; i < numberOfImages; i++, X+=80)
{       
    if (count == 4)
    {
        boundX = 5;

        boundY += 70;

        X = 0;

        count = 0;

    }

    frame1 = CGRectMake(boundX+X ,boundY+5, 70, 65);
    AsyncImageView *av1 = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
    [av1 loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[eventRow.photoArray objectAtIndex:volPhotoApp.photoGalleryIndex]]];
    av1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    volPhotoApp.photoGalleryIndex++;

    UIButton *b1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
    b1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [b1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    b1.tag = volPhotoApp.photoGalleryIndex;
    [b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    b1.enabled = YES;
    count++;

    [myScroll addSubview:av1];

    [myScroll addSubview:b1];
    totalScrollRow++;

    if (volPhotoApp.photoGalleryIndex == numberOfImages)
    {
        volPhotoApp.photoGalleryIndex = 0 ;
        break;
    }

}   
NSLog(@"%f",boundY);
NSLog(@"%d",totalScrollRow);

NSLog(@"%f",myScroll.contentSize.height);

if (boundY > myScroll.contentSize.height || totalScrollRow > 20)
{
    myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, boundY+75);
}

[super viewDidLoad];
  }
```

Thanks..

Comment: @Maulik: your code pls..

Comment: myClassName is dataSource delegate for some UITableView in your program. Maybe you forgot to delete bindings in Interface Builder?

Comment: what I did at my first try I have used UITableView then I delete the that xib file and created new one and used the scrollview .... i have also delete that old xib from hard disk..

Comment: and ya this error occurs at random.... some times it works fine and some time it doesn't !!!

Comment: Note: You should call [super viewDidLoad] first, then add your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be inheriting from UITableViewController or acting as the delegate? Without code it's only guessing.